# MySQL SELECT from two tables based on ID from URL

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a problem. I'm new in MySQL. So far, I've needed only simple queries, and everything worked fine. But, now I have a problem. I have two tables:

1. table `tarife`

   ```
   +----+---------------+
   | id |  ime_tarife   |
   +----+---------------+
   |  1 | Neka tarifa 1 |
   |  2 | Neka tarifa 2 |
   +----+---------------+
   ```
2. table `telefoni_dodatak`

   ```
   +----+--------------+-----------+-------+
   | id | telefoni_id  | tarifa_id | price |
   +----+--------------+-----------+-------+
   |  1 |           35 |         1 |   650 |
   |  2 |           35 |         2 |   700 |
   +----+--------------+-----------+-------+
   ```

All values in this table are integers.

I have URL like this `www.example.com/phones/35/` where number 35 represents id of the page (used in some third table), and it's also writen as `telefoni_id` in table `telefoni_dodatak`.

Column `tarifa_id` have id numbers from table `tarife`.

I have to get output like this in HTML, based on id from url `www.example.com/phones/35/`:

```
Neka tarifa 1 | 650
-------------------
Neka tarifa 2 | 700
```

I've tried with this query:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT ime_tarife FROM tarife WHERE id = (SELECT tarifa_id FROM telefoni_dodatak WHERE telefoni_id = :id)) AS nazivTarife FROM telefoni_dodatak WHERE telefoni_id = :id
```

but that don't work. (`nazivTarife` is not defined. Should be?)

I'm using PDO, and `:id` is that number 35 from url.

P.S. This query `SELECT * FROM telefoni_dodatak WHERE telefoni_id = :id`works fine, I'm getting both prices 650 and 700.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why are you not joining it?

```
SELECT  a.ime_tarife, b.price 
FROM    tarife a
        INNER JOIN telefoni_dodatak b
            ON a.id = b.tarifa_id 
WHERE   b.telefoni_id = 35
```

Comment: Because I'm new at this, and JOIN is really confusing for me :) I've read about JOIN from official docs and I'm just not get it :s

Comment: visit here, [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Sorry, but can you edit code in case i have more columns in table `telefoni_dodatak`, like `price_1` and `price_2`?

Comment: is this what you mean? `SELECT  a.ime_tarife, b.price,b.price_1 , b.price_2`. if youw ant to select all records just use `*`. `SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: Yes, I want to select all records, but now your `a` and `b` makes me confused, in case of all records :)

Comment: oh they are just `alias`. it is helpful when you have longer table names.